# How to set the ArangoDB Admin directory?

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to startup the ArangoDB server with:

```
→ bin/arangod --server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8529 --database.directory tmp
```

However I get a:

```
2013-05-07T12:30:30Z [83160] INFO ArangoDB 1.3.devel -- ICU 49.1.2, V8 version 3.16.14.1, SSL engine OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
2013-05-07T12:30:30Z [83160] INFO using default language 'de_DE'
2013-05-07T12:30:30Z [83160] INFO using endpoint 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' for http non-encrypted requests
2013-05-07T12:30:30Z [83160] FATAL you must specify an admin directory, giving up!
```

What is wrong? And what can I do to make the error go away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not going to "make install" ArangoDB in its final destination, but instead want to start it from the source directory, please use

```
bin/arangod -c etc/relative/arangod.conf --server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8529 --database.directory tmp
```

The configuration files in the "etc/relative" directory hold all the defines to start arangod and arangosh without installing it.